# Symfony create User with language from entity

Tags: symfony, locale

I try to setup a User creation form with FOS. There, the user specific language can be choosed from a databasetable (language).

This seems to be a bad solution for the reason that there must be an other way to give a choice between four langueges on user creation form. I'm stucking, and as far as I understand the documentation, theyre talking about website translation (this is my second step but first I need to setup the users).

Is there a nice way to get hteese languages into the creation form: actually, my form looks like

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('firstname', 'text')
        ->add('usergroups', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Group','property' => 'name'))
        ->add('language', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Language','property' => 'name'))
        ->add('lastname', 'text')
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('phone', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

It works but with

```
        ->add('language', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Language','property' => 'name'))
```

Cause an error for the reason that there are no getters and setters for it in my user class.
My User Class also don't know about the language so adding getters will bring no result :(

My User Entity:

```
<?php
// src/Pr/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Pr\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sys_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $client_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16383, nullable=true) //16383 = max varchar utf8
     */
    private $imageurl;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = true)

     */
    protected $lock_state;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $locations;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $usergroups;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5, options={"fixed" = true, "default" = "de_DE"})
     */
    private $locale = 'de_DE';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $timezone = 'UTC';
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)

     */
    private $created='1';

    //do not persist!
    protected $plain_password;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param integer $client
     * @return User
     */
    public function setClient($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Set client_id
     *
     * @param integer $clientId
     * @return User
     */
    public function setClientId($clientId)
    {
        $this->client_id = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->client_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set imageurl
     *
     * @param string $imageurl
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImageurl($imageurl)
    {
        $this->imageurl = $imageurl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get imageurl
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImageurl()
    {
        return $this->imageurl;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set lock_state
     *
     * @param integer $lockState
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLockState($lockState)
    {
        $this->lock_state = $lockState;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lock_state
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getLockState()
    {
        return $this->lock_state;
    }

    /**
     * Set locations
     *
     * @param array $locations
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLocations($locations)
    {
        $this->locations = $locations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locations
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }



    /**
     * Get locations
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getLocations()
    {
        return $this->locations;
    }


    /**
     * Set usergroups
     *
     * @param array $usergroups
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsergroups($usergroups)
    {
        $this->usergroups = $usergroups;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get usergroups
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getUsergroups()
    {
        return $this->usergroups;
    }

    /**
     * Set locale
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locale
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    /**
     * Set timezone
     *
     * @param string $timezone
     * @return User
     */
    public function setTimezone($timezone)
    {
        $this->timezone = $timezone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get timezone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTimezone()
    {
        return $this->timezone;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param array $created
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user entity is unaware of the selected language how do you intend to store the input value?

Comment: Use mapped property http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#mapped

Comment: @ferdynator: there is a entity "locale" where I would like to store the choosen language. I'm open for othere solutions (I'm a symfony newby)

Comment: Or better: how can I announce the language entity to my User?

Comment: Why don't you add a locale propperty to your user entity? This property could represent a relation between the user and the locale entities.

Comment: Please, can you gimme a hint how to realize it? This is my User Entity:

Comment: OK, I got it. I just set the entity to public. so that I can access it from My UserClass. the I easily accessed it by using" entity like this:->add('locale', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Language','property' => 'name'))